# Простота набора чисел

Tags: c, функции, циклы, вывод, простые-числа

Найдите все простые числа меньшие .
Формат входных данных:
В первой строке содержатся два целых числа:  — диапазон, в котором нужно найти все
простые числа и  — количество запросов в файле (10 <=  <= 20 000 000, 1 <=  <= 200 000).
В каждой из следующих  строк содержится по одному целому числу , для которого
нужно вывести, простое оно или нет (0 <=  < ).
Формат выходных данных:
Нужно вывести  ответов, по одному в каждой строке. Каждый ответ — это само число,
указанное в запросе, и слово prime или not в зависимости то того, является число простым
или нет.

*Мой код, в принципе, работает почти правильно. Только он 0 и 1 почему-то определяет как простые числа, хотя это не так. Подскажите, что нужно подправить, пожалуйста:*

```
#include<stdio.h>

int Simple ( int N )
{
for ( int i = 2; i*i <= N; i ++ )
if ( N % i == 0 ) return 0;
return 1;
}

int main(){
    int N, Q, i;
    scanf("%d %d", &N, &Q);
    int a[200000];
    for(int k=1; k<=Q; k++){
        scanf("%d", &a[k]);
    }
    for(int k=1; k<=Q; k++){
        if (a[k]<N){
        if ( Simple (a[k]) )
         printf ( "%d prime\n", a[k] );
        else printf ( "%d not\n", a[k] );
        getch(); }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int Simple ( int N )
{
    for ( int i = 2; i*i <= N; i ++ )
        if ( N % i == 0 ) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Поскольку и 0, и 1 явно меньше 4 (первого значения `i*i`), цикл ни разу не выполняется, и вы получаете `return 1`.

Добавьте обработку этого частного случая -

```
int Simple ( int N )
{
    if (N < 2) return 0;
    for ( int i = 2; i*i <= N; i ++ )
        if ( N % i == 0 ) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Еще два замечания... Нужен ли вам `int` или все же `unsigned int` - в плане, в общем случае нужна ли проверка отрицательных чисел? У вас она все равно не работает в исходном варианте, так как условие `i*i <= N` всегда ложно.

Второе - можно легко ускорить код в 2 раза - ведь проверка делимости на четные числа имеет смысл только в одном случае - для 2.

В итоге -

```
int Simple ( unsigned int N )
{
    if (N < 2) return 0;
    if (N == 2) return 1;
    if (N%2 == 0) return 0;
    for ( unsigned int i = 3; i*i <= N; i+=2 )
        if ( N % i == 0 ) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: но теперь при тестировании все числа получаются на выходе НЕ простые :(

Comment: код теперь, вроде, работает правильно, но теперь другая проблема... что значит Deadlock-Timeout?

Comment: Ой, я набирая спутал `i` и `N`... Про таймаут - это какая-то проверяющая система? Тогда, наверное, мешает `getch()`?

Comment: Да, проверяющая система. Если убрать getch(), появляется просто Run-Time Error

Comment: Значит, работает медленно. Тогда сначала лучше построить таблицу всех простых.

Comment: т.е. строить двумерный массив? а зачем он нужен?

Comment: Да нет. Просто один раз построить таблицу простых чисел до 20000000, второй же массив из 200000 вам просто вообще не нужен! Дайте-ка URL, повозиться немного (только прямо сейчас, а то времени у меня с полчаса...)

Comment: на почту как-то вам отправляла, сейчас еще раз перешлю

Comment: Вкратце - несколько вариантов я проверил; решето не проходит по времени. Предвычисление - что-то дает неверный ответ, но я уже должен убегать, нет времиени разбираться. Через час-другой вернусь доделаю.

Comment: думаю, можно как-то подправить мою исходную программу, чтобы она проходила по времени, но вот только где ее подправить...

Comment: Отправил письмом. Решение - предвычисление таблицы простых чисел...

Answer (score 1):

0 и 1 - это частный случай, их можно захардкодить в условии.

Ваше решение с делением хорошо, но медленное. Почему бы не воспользоваться [Решетом Эратосфена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0)?

Comment: можно и воспользоваться, но я пока не знаю как его реализовать :)

Comment: там в википедии полностью написан алгоритм же

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0#%D0%9F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4

Comment: вам в любом случае придется воспользоваться этим способом, так как решетом найти массив простых чисел до 1 миллиарда - это меньше секунды. потом прогнать по поиску 200000 чисел - это меньше секунды. А ваш вариант повесит комп надолго.

Comment: @A_Hatake деление - это самая медленная операция в математической модели компьютера.

Answer (score 0):

Решила проблему ленивым способом. Получилось вот так:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int Simple ( int N )
{
if(N==0) return 0;
if(N==1) return 0;
for ( int i = 2; i*i <= N; i ++ )
if ( N % i == 0 ) return 0;
return 1;
}

int main(){
    int N, Q, i;
    scanf("%d %d", &N, &Q);
    int a[200000];
    for(int k=1; k<=Q; k++){
        scanf("%d", &a[k]);
    }
    for(int k=1; k<=Q; k++){
        if (a[k]<N){
        if ( Simple (a[k]) )
         printf ( "%d prime\n", a[k] );
        else printf ( "%d not\n", a[k] );
        getch(); }
    }
    return 0;
}
```